# Mongodb best way to query

Tags: c#, mongodb

Hi started using mongodb with c#, finding it really cool, just wondering the best way to query

Seem to have an option of the followings

```
    var query = Query<Entity>.EQ(e => e.Id, id);
    var entity = collection.FindOne(query);
```

vs

```
    var entity = collection.Entity.AsQueryable().Single(x => x.Id == id)
```

Now the second looks more attractive to me as its what Im used to, but in terms of performance and best practice, whats the difference and whats recommended?

Comment: I don't have a clear-cut answer, but have you tried surrounding the code with a System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch and doing the query, say, a thousand times? Should give you some more info.

Comment: Considering that it is a database operation, the round-trip time to the database and back is likely to overshadow any optimizations you do in your code.

Comment: Will have to give that a try tonight, ill post the results in this thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example is using the drivers native query - Essentially creating a `QueryDocument` via the `Query<T>` helpers etc..

Your second is using Linq.

Under the hood, these both boil down to generating the same query:

```
db.entity.find({_id: 'abc123'});
```

The resultant QueryDocument is serialized as the query, in this case

```
{_id: 'abc123'}
```

According to the [linq docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/):

> Only LINQ queries that can be translated to an equivalent MongoDB query are supported. If you write a LINQ query that can’t be translated you will get a runtime exception and the error message will indicate which part of the query wasn’t supported.

To me, this would suggest there's some overhead converting LINQ queries into MongoDB queries...

I haven't tested this, but I suspect using Query is slightly more performant

Answer (score 2):

The first approach, in which you build a query and then use it to find a result, is effectively the [Specification Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern).

The second approach, being a direct LINQ query, is typically more familiar to .NET developers.

The specification pattern provides you with a reusable piece of filtering logic.  It's very useful if you frequently need to filter collections by the same criteria--and especially if the filter needs to be applied to collections from various repositories.

Here's a quick example of a possible useage of it (pardon any rough code, I've been out of C# for a while now):

```
static class WidgetSpecification  {
    function Query<Widget> AvailableWidgets() 
    {
        return new Query<Widget>.EQ(e => 
          e.StartDate <= Date.Today 
          && e.EndDate >= Date.Today 
          && e.Active == true
          && e.InStock == true);
    }
}
```

Then, anywhere in your app that you need "available widgets" you'd call something like:

```
{
    ...
    var products = getProductsFromSomewhere();
    var query = WidgetSpecifiation.AvailableWidgets();

    var availableProducts = Products.Find(query);
    ...
}
```

If you ever redefine what an "available widget" is you can update the specification and have all consumers behave the same.